# Update Metadata of document library using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to update custom metadata fields in sharepoint 2013 document library. File is uploaded in first REST call successfully but when trying to update metadata I am getting 403 forbidden error.

See my code below:

`string siteURL = "http://<somesite.com>/sites/AJG/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(" + "'/sites/AJG/Client/FRED/test.txt'" + ")/ListItemAllFields";`

It is giving result when I am putting it in browser.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(siteURL);

System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
                                                              "<username>",
                                                               "<pwd>",
                                                               "<domain>");

request.Credentials = credentials;
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
request.ContentType = "application/json; odata=verbose";
request.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
request.Headers.Add("IF-MATCH", "*");
string formDigest = GetFormDigestValue("http://<somesite.com>/sites/AJG", credentials);
request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);
string stringData = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ListItem' }, 'Code': 'FieldValue' }";
request.ContentLength = stringData.Length;
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(stringData);
writer.Flush();
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Please let me know where I am getting wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify `X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED` request header:

```
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
```

This error could occur when you set your Windows credentials on the request but still get an access denied error when requesting the data, see [Retrieving Data from a Multi-Authentication Site by Using the Client Object Model and Web Services in SharePoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh124553(v=office.14).aspx) section for a more details.